# Parse condition with a date

Tags: sql, vba, outlook

The filter query that is built for the VBA project for Otm does not work when I add the date filter.

This works

```
filter = "@SQL=( NOT(""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" LIKE '%MACHINE_GENERATED%')  )"
```

Adding the Received time filter gives an error.

> Cannot parse condition.

```
filter = "@SQL=( NOT(""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" LIKE '%MACHINE_GENERATED%') AND [ReceivedTime] > '08/20/2023 14:47:59' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `[]` in the SQL (with the `@SQL=` prefix) expressions:

```
filter = "@SQL=( NOT(""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords"" LIKE '%MACHINE_GENERATED%') AND (ReceivedTime > '08/20/2023 14:47:59') )"
```